# Opening file by file in a folder

Tags: python, xml

I m new at programing with python but currently i received a task to write a script that writes me down all ID's were the type=0 or type=1 occurs. Its an XML File that looks like this example:

```
<root>
<bla1 type="0" id = "1001" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla2 type="0" id = "1002" pvalue:="djdjd" />
<bla3 type="0" id = "1003" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla4 type="0" id = "1004" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla5 type="0" id = "1005" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla6 type="1" id = "1006" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla7 type="0" id = "1007" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla8 type="0" id = "1008" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla9 type="1" id = "1009" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla10 type="0" id = "1010" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla11 type="0" id = "1011" pvalue:="djdjd"/>
<bla12 type="0" id = "1009" pvalue:="djdjd"/>

<root>
```

So the first thing the code does is to replace basically ':=' with '=' cause that makes my xml upload causing errors. Anyway then it writes down the ID's were the type is 0 and the ID's where the the type is 1. This works perfectly for one xml file. Unfortunately i have more then just one file and i need sth like a loop that always opens the next xml file (different names) in the folder and adds always the new ID's to the ID's found in the last xml. So basically it adds always the new found id's from the new xml file.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET # required import

    XmlFile = 'ID3.xml'  # insert here the name of the XML-file, which needs to be inside the same folder as the .py file

    my_file = open('%s' % XmlFile, "r+")  # open the XML-file
    Xml2String = my_file.readlines()  # convert the file into a list strings

    XmlFile_new = []  # new list, which is filled with the modified strings
    L = len(Xml2String)  # length of the string-list
    for i in range(1, L):  # Increment starts at 0, therefore, the first line is ignored
        if ':=' in Xml2String[i]:
            XmlFile_new.append(Xml2String[i].replace(':=', '='))    # get rid of colon
        else:
            XmlFile_new.append(Xml2String[i])

    tree = ET.ElementTree(XmlFile_new)
    root = tree.getroot()

    id_0 = []   # list for id="0"
    id_1 = []   # list for id="1"
    id_one2zero = []    # list for ids, that occur twice

    for i in range(len(root)):
        if 'type="0"' in root[i]:   # check for type
            a = root[i].index("id") + 5  # search index of id
            b = a+6
            id_0.append((root[i][a:b]))  # the id is set via index slicing
        elif 'type="1"' in root[i]:  # check for type
            a = root[i].index("id") + 5
            b = a+6
            id_1.append((root[i][a:b]))
        else:
            print("Unknown type occurred")  # If there's a line without type="0" or type="1", this message gets printed
            #  (Remember: first line of the xml-file is ignored)

    for i in range(len(id_0)):  # check for ids, that occur twice
        for j in range(len(id_1)):
            if id_0[i] == id_1[j]:
                id_one2zero.append(id_0[i])
    print(id_0)
    print(id_1)
    f = open('write.xml','w')
    print >>f, 'whatever'
    print('<end>')
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this is using the `os.walk()` function. With it you can open all files in one directory or even recursively.

Here is an example how to use it:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("your/path"):
    for file in files:
        # process your file
```

If you also have other files than xml-files in your directory you can make sure you only process xml-files with the `file.endswith(".xml")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I will test it out asap :-)

Comment: ...So I guess I will have all the xml files in sth like an array, right? How do I tell python to take next and then proceed with the next etc? Can you give me maybe an example if in my case i have 3 xml's that I want to work on? Lets say: ID1.xml, ID2.xml, ID3.xml is in the folder. The name of the xml's is different but the structure is always the same. Do I need sth like a loop ?

Comment: Yes, you need a loop. I tried to explain this in my example where I have provided a loop that would work. `os.walk()` returns a list of files (in your case `["ID1.xml", "ID2.xml", "ID3.xml"]` and `for file in files:` loops over all those files in the list. Whatever you write where I put my comment `# process your file` will be executed for all files